# Pivot table, how to use VBA to error check automatically filtered list

Tags: vba, excel, filtering, pivot-table

i have been using the code below to set all the pivot tables in a report to filter to the same stock period.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)    
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Const strField As String = "stkperiod" 'This is the name of the pivot table filed you wish to change"

    If Target.Address = "$C$6" Then    
        For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            For Each pt In WS.PivotTables
                With pt.PageFields(strField)
                    .ClearAllFilters
                    .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = True
                    .CurrentPage = Target.Value
                End With
            Next pt
        Next WS
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
End Sub
```

The Code appears to work very well until the stock period is not found. 
if for example i set the stock period to 12/2018 the pivot tables filter is automatically set to "all" results as 2018 is a future date and not part of my data set.
I would much rather the VBA set the filter to be "Blank" if the date is not in the list.

The above code does not give me any errors, but my users are getting confused, they think "wow we have had a good month already and its only the second day of trading!" what they don't understand is the report is now set to all results for the year.

The tricky part is the date range in the tables is not always the same. if one pivot has a value for 12/2018 i would like to total that pivot and show zero on the others that do not have data for this date.

I assumed if i could make the report pick from the below list, i could make it pick the blank option. 
[image: Pivot Filter]

I though this would be fairly simple.....can't i pre-filter all pivots to be "blank" and then after apply my custom filter? but i just don't know enough VBA to get it to do what i want!

Any help you could offer would be amazing, thank you for your time.
R.

Answer (score 1):

> i just don't know enough VBA to get it to do what i want!

I am going to use the below scenario for demonstration. Please undrstand it and apply it for your case as applicable.

Let's say our data and pivot looks like this

[image]

Now the logic that we will follow is

1. Check if the field exists in the pivottable or not
2. If it doesn't exists then hide all items except `blank`. I am assuming that there is a blank item else you will get an error.

Code

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pitem As PivotItem

    For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        If DoesFieldExist("MickyMouse", pt) Then

        Else
            '~~> it the field doesnt exist
            For Each pitem In pt.PivotFields("Name").PivotItems
               If pitem.Value <> "(blank)" Then pitem.Visible = False
            Next
        End If
    Next pt
End Sub

'~~> Function to check if a field exists or not in a pivot table
Function DoesFieldExist(fld As String, ptbl As PivotTable) As Boolean
    For Each pf In ptbl.PageFields
        If pf.Name = fld Then
            DoesFieldExist = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next pf
End Function
```

When you run the above code, since there is no field called "MickyMouse", the items will be hidden.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the option, but i don't have a break in the data. 
I hoped rather than pick Raj or Sid, i could automatically pick blank from the row label.
Thanks again for the time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Below are two ways to handle this:

You can use Data > Data Validation. In the setup below, the input has to be less than today's date, else it will not allow the input.

[image]

Or, if you are wanting to use VBA, insert the snippet below right after this line:

If Target.Address = "$C$6" Then

```
Dim stkPeriod As Date

stkPeriod = Range("C6")

If stkPeriod >= Date Then

    MsgBox "Use a different date range."
    Exit Sub

    ' or you can do something else such as verifying
    '    that the date is present within your data table etc.

End If
```

Comment: This doesn't quite do what i want.....one of the pivot tables does contain the future date. so I want that to total that pivot, but show zero on the tables that do not.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Oh, ok sorry I might have misunderstood. Depending on where the error is occurring, perhaps a On Error Resume Next would do the trick. Could you specify in your question which line it errors on?

Comment: i don't get any errors at all.
the pivot table is set to "all" as it cant find my filter.
i shall update the post to be a little more clear. TY